# How to get response from an API that returns same values with different answers?

Tags: javascript, json, api

(Sorry if the title doesn't make much sense, I couldn't figure out how to word it correctly)

So I'm trying to get the response from an API, but the API returns multiple responses with the same name.
Ex of a response:

`{
    "xuid": 2535436668322645,
    "state": "Online",
    "devices": [
        {
            "type": "XboxOne",
            "titles": [
                {
                    "id": 714681658,
                    "name": "Home",
                    "placement": "Background",
                    "state": "Active",
                    "lastModified": "2016-11-22T23:45:08.8296994Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 74304278,
                    "activity": {
                        "richPresence": "Lvl 30 in Hudson Yards"
                    },
                    "name": "Tom Clancy's The Division",
                    "placement": "Full",
                    "state": "Active",
                    "lastModified": "2016-11-22T23:45:08.8296994Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

So I was wondering, how would I be able to get the ID from the "second" response using JavaScript? (The one that says "Tom Clancy's The Division" in the name part) Thanks!

Comment: How do you access the first one?

Comment: @yuriy636 I'm not sure, whenever I try to access it like I would for any other part of the api (like xuid or state) it gives me this error in the console: ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined `I can post my code if you'd like EDIT: radmation's way worked :)

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(JSON_DATA);        console.log(obj.devices[0].titles[1].id)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should get you on the right track (untested)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(YOUR_JSON);
obj->devices[0]->titles[1]->id // second id
```

Comment: that looks like php?

Comment: @bergi no it's not this way ended up working. I would mark it as answer but for some reason it wants me to wait for a couple minutes. Thanks Radmation :)

Comment: @ConnorS `->` certainly is a syntax error in JavaScript

Comment: @bergi oh yeah I didn't copy and paste it exactly I just meant the devices[0] and titles[1] part worked